# How to replace NOT IN with NOT EXISTS in this code?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, not-exists, notin

I have only tried to replace NOT IN operator with NOT EXISTS in the following code.
However, it is giving me an "Invalid Relational Operator error".

How can I correct this error? Am I missing something important? Please help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'v1',
                   'v2',
                   f.apples,
                   f.bananas,
                   f.oranges     
FROM fruits f
     WHERE f.code = 'F1' 
     AND f.buyer_fruit_code
     NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT c.color_code
                FROM colors c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NOT IN` operator means something different from a `NOT EXISTS` clause.  Among other things, `NOT EXISTS` is not an operator.  Perhaps you want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'v1',
               'v2',
               f.apples,
               f.bananas,
               f.oranges     
FROM fruits f
WHERE
  f.code = 'F1' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT c.color_code
    FROM colors c
    WHERE c.color_code = f.buyer_fruit_code
  )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'v1',
                       'v2',
                       f.apples,
                       f.bananas,
                       f.oranges     
    FROM fruits f
    LEFT JOIN color_code c ON f.fruit_code=c.color_code
         WHERE f.code = 'F1' 
         AND c.color_code is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks I would love to try this but I'm specifically looking to replace 'NOT IN' with 'NOT EXISTS' here.